# Bootstrap container with z-index does not stay hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hidden

I am having a bit of a hard time trying to solve an issue with a Bootstrap container that I am trying to hide using jQuery. For some reason after `fadeOut()` executing, the `<div>` returns back on screen and does not stay hidden. My code bellow.

CSS:

```
.container-fluid
  {
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $( "#btn_entrar" ).click(function() {
  $( "#entrar" ).fadeOut( "slow");
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="entrar" class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row my-auto">
        <table class="table table-image">
          <tr>
            <td><img class="img-fluid" src="/img/TlmI1dedo512.jpg"></td>
            <td><img class="img-fluid" src="/img/TlmI2dedos512.jpg"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="img-fluid" src="/img/TlmIRodar512.jpg"></td>
            <td><img class="img-fluid" src="/img/TlmGiroscopio512.gif"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried several approaches but no joy so far, can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: There must be some other code on the page. This seems to do what you intend. Can you include more code, I was unable to reproduce that behavior using what you provided.

Comment: In fact there is. Please have a look at the url https://www.digimatter.pt/PT/Moradia_resp.html . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this also works just fine, tried it on JSFiddle just now: [https://jsfiddle.net/17erftug/14/][Fiddle]

The only thing i did is to remove `$(function() {` bc. `$('#someID').click(function() {
// yourCode here
});` triggers a function already.

Do you get any errors in your console or something?

Comment: No errors but you can have a look in this url https://www.digimatter.pt/PT/Moradia_resp.html after the progress bar finishes and the button appears when you click button fades but comes back straigh away. Thanks PS: this is the mobile version so u need to resize the screen.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Because with Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 it works just fine for me. PS: Seems to be a nice app!

Comment: thanks for the reply, as you can see i have found the solution already.  Thanks for the complements regarding the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the erratic behavior, as soon as i removed "d-flex" from div container it started working as expected! Thanks!